# Global Minimum of Multivariate Polynomial is coNP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-complete, np-hard, polynomials

Is the following problem coNP-complete?

**Inputs:**

- $p=$ a possibly non-convex multivariate polynomial over $\mathbb Z$
- $k\in \mathbb Z$, an integer

**Question:**

Is $\forall x\in\mathbb Z: p(x)\geq k$?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?